# SMS gateway - square brackets []

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

when i send an SMS via PHP mail using number@txt.bell.ca, the SMS I receive starts with two square brackets. Like "[]". Any idea why?

Comment: just a simple php mail function. sends an email to number@txt.bell.ca, which gets passed on by bell servers to my phone as an SMS. If i use the same mail function to send an email, there are no square brackets.

Comment: What happens if you send the E-Mail from a normal mail client?

Comment: yahoo mail delivers a normal text, yet gmail ads in these brackets

Comment: what yahoo is doing differently i have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it going as a multi-part message or a single PDU?

At a guess one of the aggregators / gateways along the route is adding in a multi-part header like [1/2], but getting it slightly wrong for a single PDU message.